# two home laptops accessing wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I have two laptop computers that are wi-fi accessible. But I cannot be on both computers on the internet at the same time. if i'm connected on one computer and my husband tries to use the other one, the one that wasn't connected first just spins and never produces an internet page and i get a "timed out" error.  why is that?

Comment: In the internet connection settings for both computers, are they set to "obtain an IP address automatically", or is an IP address explicitly set? Are you using Windows 7, 8, OSX, Linux? What is the make and model of your router?

Comment: Try to login to the wireless router's home page, and view the "connected devices" status info.  See if both laptops are connected.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of router are you using? 
When you only use one computer at a time does loading a page take forever? It seems like you might be fighting for bandwidth, but we need more information.

What I suggest you do is this (with the information given):

- Go over and check your WEP key(if you're using one) for both laptops
- Reset the router(usually does the trick)
- Check the router and see if it's allowing multiple devices to connect
- Try and connect a different device besides the laptop

This doesn't seem too complicated and can be done with simple debugging and troubleshooting.

Comment: *"Check the router and see if it's allowing multiple devices to connect"* -- This is so vague that it's useless advice.  And what wireless router property or attribute controls single versus multiple connections?